# Can't get blueprint CSS plugins working?

Tags: css, user-interface, web-applications, blueprint-css

I am trying to use blueprint css, and everything seems to be working, but I can't seem to get any of the plugins loaded up.

I tried just including the requisuite CSS files, but I think there must be another step because even though the browser sees the CSS files the elements on the page are not changing (in firebug on Chrome I get there are no rules on this stylesheet when I try to look at the plugin css page) .

What do I need to do to get the Vanilla blueprint CSS + the buttons, fancy-type, link-icons, and rtl going?  Just all the stuff they include in the default download.

I feel like I am missing something besides just including CSS.

Comment: Do you have any code you can show to give us a better idea of how you are importing it?

Comment: Yeah that was it.  Instead of using <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/screen.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> I was using <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/plugins/fancy-type/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

Comment: Best to answer your own question for future reference.

Comment: this isn't a general question about programming, it's a "fix-my-code-for-me" question, and without showing us the code or the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/plugins/fancy-type/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
```

instead of

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/plugins/fancy-type/screen.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```